# How to abstract go to goal angle?

Tags: navigation

I'm currently developing a pygame based go to goal behavior. I approached the goal by Euclidean distance and vectorized mathematics. Here is the code

```
def move(roborect,i):

no_plants=len(test_x)
if(no_plants>i):
    dx = 8*test_x[i]-roborect.x
    dy = test_y[i]-roborect.y
    distance = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    print(distance)
    if distance > 70:
        vx = dx * 2/ distance 
        vy = dy * 2 / distance 
    #print(vx,vy)
        #print(roborect.x,roborect.y)
        roborect.x += vx
        roborect.y += vy
    else:
        return 1
```

But I could not understand to approach the orientation of the robot towards to goal.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?  This seems like it should simply be the inverse tangent of dy/dx.

Comment: I have tried try:
            grad=(test_x[i]-roborect.y)/(test_y[i]-roborect.x)
            angle=math.degrees(math.atan(grad))
            print(angle)
        except:
            pass

Comment: Theres is possibility grad = infinitie.. so in the exception you should handle that math error.. except : angle = 90

Comment: Try atan2(dy, dx).

Comment: Yes, I used dx/dy instead of dy/dx